# Python create array of certain depth

Tags: python, arrays, list

So basically what i want my script to do is output something like

```
somelist = ([0,0],[0,0])
```

given x = 2.
so if x were 3 it would be

```
somelist = ([0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0])
```

what I've come up with so far is

```
somelist = ([0] * x) * x
```

but this simply returns

```
somelist = [0,0,0,0]
```

Anybody know of a simple way to do this?

Comment: You don't have any arrays, you have a some `tuple` objects and `list` objects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old singleton `tuple` issue. Add a comma or else the parentheses will be meaningless (interpreted merely as precedence/grouping markers):

```
somelist = ([0] * x,) * x
#                  ^--- makes all the difference
```

Comment: nice, that worked, thanks! bit of a stupid decision in my opinion, as it seems like a really sketchy way of doing things, but it works

Comment: It is a very common pattern though. But if you think of it, parentheses are overworked otherwise.